# Get logs for a transaction without actually sending the transaction

Tags: transactions, logs, openethereum, transaction-trace, alchemy

I'm trying to simulate a transaction without actually sending the transaction. The `trace_call` method (on Alchemy) returns 3 types of traces - `vmTrace`, `trace`, `stateDiff`. The `trace` object returns all the `call`, `staticall` and `delegatecall` in the entire transaction. It also provides `calldata` and return values for all these internal calls.  Example `trace` for the transaction `0x1dafb48e048b11ee1c6e1ce754eface63c632f9e8b79c159290964bbee9d110f` on kovan.

```json
{
  "action": {
    "callType": "call",
    "from": "0x6303e43320b036084a539d622a996e56c2110a16",
    "gas": "0x1af6",
    "input": "0xd0e30db0",
    "to": "0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c",
    "value": "0xb1a2bc2ec50000"
  },
  "result": {
    "gasUsed": "0x1af6",
    "output": "0x"
  },
  "subtraces": 0,
  "traceAddress": [],
  "type": "call"
}
```

But this doesn't return way logs. One way to do this, is to parse the `vmTrace` that provides the stack push and memory updates at each opcode's execution. It looks something like this.

```json
{
  "cost": 3,
  "ex": {
    "mem": null,
    "push": [
      "0x40"
    ],
    "store": null,
    "used": 6896
  },
  "pc": 2,
  "sub": null
}
```

But since we don't know what opcode is being executed at a particular program counter, we'll need to rerun the transaction locally on an evm to keep track of when the `log[0-4]` opcodes are run and capture the stack value at that time. But running an evm just to parse out logs seem excessive. Is there an alternative for this? Geth's `debug_transaction` offers this but there isn't any API that provides access to it.

Is there any other way to get the logs for a transaction without actually sending the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

This article by Banteg may be helpful: https://banteg.mirror.xyz/vZySVJ4Wvf4tKhgskbEIcHAlqG20wifUy807bzfEsp8

Otherwise, you will have to fork using ganache/anvil and send the transaction or simulate locally using some other method.